# @OneToOne not deleted referred element on change

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one, hibernate-cascade

I have `@OneToOne` unidirectional relation between `Parent` and `Child`. When `Parent` is being merge I want to delete `Child`, when provided `Child` object is different than that existed in database. This is my relation in `Parent` class:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "object_id")
private Child child;
```

Comment: Could you post the code you use in order to merge/delete?

Comment: it's nothing special: em.merge(parent);

Comment: What version of hibernate are you using? See question here and my answer suggesting bug around this functionality in 4.1.8 fixed in 4.2.7: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20280271/hibernate-jpa-onetoone-orphan-removal-still-not-working-as-of-4-2-7-4-3-0-cr1/20282447#20282447

Comment: @Ziemo I meant the way you "delete child". Since it's unidirectional I guess you just do parent.setChild(null) or something similar, do you?